# Is there a way other than using try & except to iterate through a list that has str and float values without having errors?

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner and its my first question here, forgive me if I am slow.

I'm trying to iterate a list and when '中旬' is detected, I want to change '中旬' to a specific date and do other stuff as well. If I avoid using try and except in this code, 'TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable' will occur.

```
for col_num, col in enumerate(date_list):
  for row_num, date in enumerate(col):
    try:
      if "中旬" in date:
        if date_checker == None:
          date_checker = date
```

The following is the list I am iterating and the values are extracted from an Excel dataframe.

```
[[' 08 月', 
  '中旬', 
  0.0, 
  5000.0, 
  75000.0, 
  0.0, 
  0.0, 
  126000.0, 
  0.0, 
  0.0, 
  9000.0,  
  93000.0, 
  205000.0, 
  205000.0, 
  30000.0, 
  30000.0, 
  0.0, 
  5000.0, 
  45600.0, 
  22848.0, 
  851448.0, 
  851448.0], 
 [nan, 
  '下旬', 
  0.0, 
  0.0, 
  72500.0, 
  20000.0, 
  0.0, 
  124000.0, 
  2000.0, 
  0.0, 
  9000.0, 
  89000.0, 
  205000.0, 
  200000.0, 
  30000.0, 
  30000.0, 
  0.0, 
  5000.0, 
  45600.0, 
  22848.0, 
  854948.0, 
  854948.0]]
```

I tried using with suppress to avoid the error but it doesnt work.

[image: I tried using WITH Suppress and the same error appears.]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `in`…?!

Comment: You could first check if `data` is a `str`  using `if isinstance(data, str):` and the your next if.

Comment: That looks pretty regular: first two elements are `str` values, the rest are floats. Take advantage of that knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way how to achieve this:

```py
>>> my_list = [0, '中旬', 1]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
...     if item == '中旬':
...         my_list[index] = 666
... 
>>> my_list
[0, 666, 1]
```

More generally

```
>>> my_list = [0, '中旬abc', 1]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
...     if type(item) is str and item.startswith('中旬'):
...         my_list[index] = 666
... 
>>> my_list
[0, 666, 1]
```

The trick in the second example is the lazy evaluation. If the `item` is not a string, the rest of the condition is not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use list comprehension (replace '<specific_date>' with date string or datetime).

```
my_list_of_list = [[' 08 月', '中旬', 0.0, 5000.0], ['中旬','下旬', 0.0, 0.0]] # sample list of list

for i, my_list in enumerate(my_list_of_list):
    my_list_of_list[i] = [x if x != "中旬" else '<specific_date>' for x in my_list]

print(my_list_of_list)
# [[' 08 月', '<specific_date>', 0.0, 5000.0], ['<specific_date>', '下旬', 0.0, 0.0]]
```